# add fuzziness to elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a query for an autocomplete/suggestions index that looks like this:

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "'"+search_text+"'",
            "type": "bool_prefix",
            "fields": [
                "company_name",
                "company_name._2gram",
                "company_name._3gram"  
            ]
        }       
      }
  }
```

This query works exactly as I want it to. However I want to add fuzziness:"AUTO" to this query. I read the documentation and tried adding it like this:

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": {
                "fuzzy": {
                    "value": "'"+search_text+"'",
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            },
            "type": "bool_prefix",
            "fields": [
                "company_name",
                "company_name._2gram",
                "company_name._3gram"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a this error

````
```
"type": "parsing_exception",
"reason": "[multi_match] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [query]",```
````

This is causing my query not to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add a [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html). To add fuzziness to a [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) you need to add the fuzziness property as described here :

Since you are using [bool_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types) as the type of multi-match query, so it creates a [match_bool_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-match-bool-prefix-query.html#query-dsl-match-bool-prefix-query) on each field that analyzes its input and constructs a bool query from the terms. Each term except the last is used in a term query. The last term is used in a prefix query.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "company_name": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type",
        "max_shingle_size": 3
      },
      "serviceTitle": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type",
        "max_shingle_size": 3
      },
      "services": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type",
        "max_shingle_size": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "company_name":"sequencing how shingles are actually used"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
   {
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "sequensing how shingles",
            "type": "bool_prefix",
            "fields": [
                "company_name",
                "company_name._2gram",
                "company_name._3gram"  
            ],
            "fuzziness":"auto"
        }       
      }
  }
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65153201",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.5465959,
        "_source": {
          "company_name": "sequencing how shingles are actually used"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**If you want to query `sequensing`, and get the above document, then you need to change the type of multi-match from `bool_prefix` to another [type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types) according to your use case.**

Comment: Hmm, doesn't appear to work. When I query: "sequencing" I'll get 700 results, but if I query: "sequensing" I'll get no results

Comment: @BrianGuan To check the possible values of fuzziness please refer to this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness.

Comment: @BrianGuan your search query looks fine, can you please share your index mapping as well as sample index data as well ?

Comment: ```
{
    "autocomplete": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "company_name": {
                    "type": "search_as_you_type",
                    "max_shingle_size": 3
                },
                "serviceTitle": {
                    "type": "search_as_you_type",
                    "max_shingle_size": 3
                },
                "services": {
                    "type": "search_as_you_type",
                    "max_shingle_size": 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrianGuan can you please share sample index data and expected search result ?